# Javascript function does not exit the function wehn the condtion failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have following code which process a queue and I need to exist the function when there are no messages in the queue and there is no enough time to process more messages. My problem is, it doesn't jump out of the function upon failing the condition and I think it's due to that this a recursive function but I cannot figure it out.

```
/**
 * Check if there is enough time to process more messages
 *
 * @param {} context
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
async function enoughTimeToProcess(context) {
  return context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() > 230000;
}

/**
 * Consume the queue and increment usages
 *
 * @param context
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
async function process(context) {
  const messagesPerRequest = queueConst.messagesPerRequest;
  const messagesToBeDeleted = [];

  const queue = new queueClient();

  const messages = await queue.getMessages(messagesPerRequest);

  if (messages === undefined) {
    if (await enoughTimeToProcess(context) === true) {
      await process(context);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  const responses = messages.map(async(messageItem) => {
    const messageBody = JSON.parse(messageItem.Body);
    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(messageBody.Message);

    const accountId = parsedMessage[0].context.accountId;
    let code = parsedMessage[0].context.code;

    // Our DB support only lowercase characters in the path
    code = code.toLowerCase();

    const service = parsedMessage[0].name;
    const count = parsedMessage[0].increment;

    const storageResponse = await incrementUsage(
      { storageClient: storage, code, accountId, service, count }
    );

    if (storageResponse) {
      messagesToBeDeleted.push({
        Id: messageItem.MessageId,
        ReceiptHandle: messageItem.ReceiptHandle,
      });
    }

    return 1;
  });

  const processedMessages = await Promise.all(responses);
  const processedMessagesCount = processedMessages.length;

  if (messagesToBeDeleted.length > 0) {
    console.log(`${processedMessagesCount} messages processed.`);
    await queue.deleteMessageBatch(messagesToBeDeleted);
  }

  if (await enoughTimeToProcess(context) === true) {
    await process(context);
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: why is `enoughTimeToProcess` async? why would you `await` it, there's nothing asynchronous about it!

Comment: Otherwise it won't wait until I get the result from `enoughTimeToProcess`

Comment: but ... there's nothing asynchronous in that function ... is there? if so, you're not waiting for it in that function anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be when messages are undefined and there is still enough time, because the recursive function is going to be called infinite times, because it always accomplishes both conditions, and probably it exceeds the available resources.
Try to sleep some time before calling process function again, just to be sure it is the problem

Comment: `the recursive function is going to be called infinite times` - not likely - with all those `await`s in there

Comment: susoPisto It is not. It stops when there is not enough time. My problem is it does not jump out of the function even it reaches `else` statement.